# Perform loop through process on all sheets at once

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have workbook having multiple sheets and having same data on it. Currently I am using macro that .autofilterand copy paste on respective sheets. I am using looping process like:-

```
   Sub SCRIPT()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("SCRIPT").Range("A3:P100").ClearContents
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lrc As Long, LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long
    Dim key1 As String
    key1 = InputBox("Type Script Name", "Title")
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (ws.Name <> "SCRIPT") And (ws.Name <> "MARKET") And (ws.Name <> "CHAIN") Then
    ws.Range("AE1:AJ500").ClearContents
    ws.Range("CB1:CH500").ClearContents
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=key1
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="28-Jan-16"
    lrc = ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("D1:D" & lrc).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="CE"
    ws.Range("L2:L" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("AG2")
    ws.Range("C2:C" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("AE2")
    ws.Range("L2:L" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("CD2")
    ws.Range("C2:C" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("CB2")
    ws.Range("C2:C" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("AH2")
    ws.Range("I2:I" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("AJ2")
    ws.Range("I2:I" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("CH2")
    ws.Range("M2:M" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("CF2")
    AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Range("D1:D" & lrc).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="PE"
    ws.Range("L2:L" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("AF2")
    ws.Range("L2:L" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("CC2")
    ws.Range("I2:I" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("AI2")
    ws.Range("I2:I" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("CG2")
    ws.Range("M2:M" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("CE2")
    AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter
    ws.Columns("AE:AJ").Sort key1:=ws.Columns("AE"), Order1:=xlDescending
    ws.Columns("CB:CH").Sort key1:=ws.Columns("CB"), Order1:=xlDescending

    ws.Range("P1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=key1
    ws.Range("P1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="EQ"
    ws.Range("R2:U" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("AM2")
    ws.Range("Z2:Z" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("AL2")
    ws.Range("P2:P" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("AK2")
    AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Range("P1").AutoFilter
    End If

    If (ws.Name <> "SCRIPT") And (ws.Name <> "MARKET") And (ws.Name <> "CHAIN") Then
    LR1 = Sheets("SCRIPT").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LR2 = ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("AK2:AZ" & LR2).Copy
    Sheets("SCRIPT").Range("A" & LR1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ws.Range("AK2:AR" & LR2).Copy
    Sheets("CHAIN").Range("A" & LR1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next ws
    Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SCRIPT").Range("A1"))
    Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CHAIN").Range("A1"))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Filtering huge data on each sheet. Therefore takes lot of time to finished process while looping each sheet. Does there any other way that perform looping task on all sheets at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a crack at this. First things first - always qualify *where* you're doing something e.g. `AutoFilterMode = False` should be `ws.AutoFilterMode = False`.

Your variable names are lacking - `lrc`, `LR1` and `LR2` give me no idea as to what they are being used for or if they are different from one another. Same goes for `key1` - it's for a "Script Name" according to the inputbox, so why not name is `ScriptName` or `ScriptNameKey`? And `ws` as Worksheet, why not say `MyWorksheet` or `CurrentWorksheet`?

You're clearing out `Sheets("SCRIPT")` but I don't know why, I don't see anything going back to it.

Your indentation is difficult to follow, your for loops and if blocks should be offset like this -

```
key1 = InputBox("Type Script Name", "Title")
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
         If (ws.Name <> "SCRIPT") And (ws.Name <> "MARKET") And (ws.Name <> "CHAIN") Then
              ws.Range("AE1:AJ500").ClearContents
              ws.Range("CB1:CH500").ClearContents
         End If
    Next
```

It makes it a lot easier to read. You can actually indent several lines in the VBE by highlighting and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

When you're working with all those `.Range` elements, you can use a `With` block -

```
 key1 = InputBox("Type Script Name", "Title")
    
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If (ws.Name <> "SCRIPT") And (ws.Name <> "MARKET") And (ws.Name <> "CHAIN") Then
                With ws
                    .Range("AE1:AJ500").ClearContents
                    
                    .Range("P1").AutoFilter
                End With
            End If
         Next
```

This will make it less cluttered. You should also use some comments to explain why things are happening -

```
 'These ranges need to be cleared to ensure the formatting of xxx doesn't change as it reaches the destination
 .Range("AE1:AJ500").ClearContents
 .Range("CB1:CH500").ClearContents
 'We filter on these two criteria because that allows ....
 .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=key1
 .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="28-Jan-16"
```

Speaking of your autofilters why not

```
Dim FilterDate as Date
FilterDate = Now() 'or whatever the date needs to be
```

Now you don't have to go into the code to find it.

The same goes for your second criteria, why not give those variables at the top as strings and then use the variables, that way if anything changes you can just change it at the top.

In your second `If` block you are moving between `ws` and two defined sheets. Why not give those sheets a variable as well?

Personally I don't like all the `.Copy Destination` methods. I like to work directly with the locations like this -

```
.Range("AG2") = .Range("L2:L" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
.Range("AE2") = .Range("C2:C" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
.Range("CD2") = .Range("L2:L" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

This has the added benefit that if you want to change the worksheets within your `If` block, you can just slap on a sheet variable.

Also what's up with this -

```
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SCRIPT").Range("A1"))
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CHAIN").Range("A1"))
```

The second one negates the first one, or are you just making sure nothing is still selected on those sheets? Nothing should be `.Select`ed anyway.

#### If you need some more speed try doing these along with `ScreenUpdating`

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Just remember to turn them back on when you're finished.

One more thing, I don't see any error handling, what happens if there's an error? It will stop and you'll need to loop through all the sheets again once it's fixed.

Oh - also use `Option Explicit` on the top, you may have caught some of the things I mentioned just by compiling with that engaged.